# Show that Q, as a Z-module, is a direct summand in a direct product of copies of Q/Z.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

> Prove that $\Bbb Q$, as a $\Bbb Z$-module, is a direct summand in a direct product of copies of $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$.

This is a problem from Hilton and Stammbach's *Homological Algebra*. 
If this is true, then there exists a homomorphism from the direct product of some copies of Q/Z to Q. But if the number of the copies is infinite, it isn't necessary that only a finite number of components have non-zero values. So how to define this homomorphism to Q?

Comment: Who says that a homomorphism $\prod A \to B$ has to factor through a finite number of projections?

Comment: It's just my illusion. Of course I know it's not true.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the direct product $G=(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})^{\mathbb{N}}$; this group is not torsion, because you can take the element
$$
x=\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\mathbb{Z}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}
$$
which is not annihilated by any integer. Thus $G/t(G)\ne0$, where $t(G)$ denotes the torsion subgroup of $G$. But $G/t(G)$ is a torsion free divisible group, so it is a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Q}$. So $\mathbb{Q}$ is a direct summand of $G/t(G)$. Since $t(G)$ is divisible, it splits, so $G=t(G)\oplus H$, where $H\cong G/t(G)$.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly an answer that I want.

Comment: As simple and direct as possible: very nice. +1

Comment: Or alternatively, there's an explicit injective homomorphism $q\mapsto(q,q/2,q/3,\dots)$ from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})^{\mathbb{N}}$, which splits because $\mathbb{Q}$ is injective. But both these proofs use the Axiom of Choice, and I suspect that it's necessary, and you won't be able to construct an explicit non-zero homomorphism from $(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})^\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @JeremyRickard Yes, the splitting morphism for my example needs somehow to find a basis of $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}}$. Yours needs some (weak) version of the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 1):

We know every abelian group sits inside a direct product of copies of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, hence we have an exact sequence $$0 \to \mathbb{Q} \to \prod_{i \in I} (\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})_{i} \to ( \ \prod_{i \in I}(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})_{i}) /\mathbb{Q} \to 0.$$ Now since $\mathbb{Q}$ is divisible, hence injective, the sequence splits. 
We are done.